# angular.js dependent services (geolocation api) not resolving promises

Tags: angularjs, service, geolocation, promise

I'm trying to obtain the users location from the browser and then query the openwathermap api to find their current weather. Right now the plunker below simply gets the users location and makes a hardcoded openweathermap api request. I can log the user's location to the console, but the promises do not appear to be resolving correctly in updating the $scope's weather property with the returned response from the openweathermap API. It appears that line 30 of app.js is never invoked (e.g. userLocator.getLocation.then() .... )

http://plnkr.co/8v3Rw0zSBdMqbmfO3f31

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on this blog post about non-angular async function and why you should wrap them in $scope.$apply or in $rootScope.$apply:

http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Here is a fixed / working version of your code sample!

http://plnkr.co/edit/xGx47zi8RerbJXpWP67v?p=preview